# Fill in an integer range by group in a column

Tags: r

The example is pretty self-explanatory. I have a year range in a column and I can't figure out how to expand that so that it includes each individual year. Solutions of all r variants are welcomes.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)

## If I have a data.frame like this:

foo <- tribble(
  ~id, ~year, 
  1, 2011, 
  1, 2013,
  2, 2009, 
  2, 2011
)

## And I'd like fill those missing years so it looked like this:

bar <- tribble(
  ~id, ~year, 
  1, 2011, 
  1, 2012,
  1, 2013,
  2, 2009,
  2, 2010,
  2, 2011
)

## I tried something like this:

foo %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(full_seq(year, 1))
#> Error: Column `full_seq(year, 1)` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 3

## But that obviously isn't right.
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the addition of `tidyr`, you can do:

```
foo %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 summarise(year = list(seq(min(year), max(year), 1))) %>%
 unnest()

     id  year
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  2011
2     1  2012
3     1  2013
4     2  2009
5     2  2010
6     2  2011
```

Or:

```
foo %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 complete(year = seq(min(year), max(year), 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (mostly) base R solution:

```
ids <- unique(foo$id)

l <- foo %>% 
  split(foo$id) %>% 
  lapply(function(x) seq(min(x$year), max(x$year)))

for(i in 1:length(l)){
  l[[i]] <- data.frame(year = l[[i]])
  l[[i]]$id <- ids[i]
}

dplyr::bind_rows(l)

  year id
1 2011  1
2 2012  1
3 2013  1
4 2009  2
5 2010  2
6 2011  2
```